# How can I get an IWebBrowser2 reference to the Internet Explorer window opened by clicking on a link?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, iwebbrowser2

Suppose I open a new Internet Explorer window by, for example, clicking a link with target="_blank" in the HTML link. Further suppose I'm doing so programmatically via COM. I realize I can attach to the DWebBrowserEvents2::NewWindow3 event, and be notified when a new window will be opened. How do I get a reference to that newly opened window so I can manipulate it also?

Things to note:

- I specifically do not want to cancel
  the NewWindow event and instantiate
  and return a new blank browser window
  in the ppDisp argument if I can help
  it.
- I've thought about searching for
  each IE window (using FindWindow or some such), asking for its
  location, and comparing it to the
  bstrUrl argument, but I don't think
  that will work if the target has a
  redirection in it.
- This is for an automated testing framework, so I am
  specifically driving Internet
  Explorer, not a hosted WebBrowser
  control.
- I'm fully aware this will not find windows created by showModalDialog().

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about how you're doing this?  Do you have a BHO that is doing the driving, or some external process?  If so, what is it?

Comment: This is not a BHO, but an external process. It happens to be written in C#, but could just as easily be C++, Java, or even Ruby. I'm well aware of the UAC and Protected Mode issues I face with this approach, but for the purposes of this question, let's assume they do not exist.